# Avoid printing line breaks in shell script

Tags: unix, script

```
while read pos; do 
     string1=`echo $pos | cut -c 20-38`
     string2="=$pos" 
     string3="$string1 $string2" 
     echo "$string3" 
done < file
```

This is the code of my script. I want to display the output in one single line, but the output comes on different lines. **How can I do this?**

> ex- pos = abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz string1 = 1234567890QWERTYUXY string2 = abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz

output wanted :

> 1234567890QWERTYUXY abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz

Comment: What operating system and what shell you are using?

Answer (score 3):

At first, there is multiple typos in your script. Apart from that, you can use

```
echo -n "$string3 "
```

to print variable `string3`, without adding linebreak after that.

From `man echo`:

```
   -n     do not output the trailing newline
```

Comment: echo - n is not available,it does nt work

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu (http://askubuntu.com/questions/27705/concatenation-of-two-command-in-one-single-command), then `-n` should be available, unless you are using some exotic shell.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `tr -d '\n'` at the end of the `$string1` assignment to remove the line break that is present in your file:

```
while read pos; do 
     string1=`echo $pos | cut -c 20-38 | tr -d '\n'`
     string2="=$pos" 
     string3="$string1 $string2" 
     echo "$string3" 
done < file
```

note that however, this will give the output:

```
QWERTYUXY.tar.gz =abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz
```

with `pos = abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz` and the script you gave.

Comment: it works but there is one problem..... i need to do one more thing which i didnt mention------ echo "$string3" >> some_file it does not work in this case. string 1 is displayed on terminal and string 2 on the some_file. i want both strings to be displayed in 1 file in some_file.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options, but the way I would recommend is `printf`.

It doesn't print a newline by default, so changing your `echo` to a `printf` should remove the unwanted newline.

```
while read pos; do 
    string1=`printf "%s" $pos | cut -c 20-38`
    string2="=$pos" 
    string3="$string1 $string2" 
    printf "%s\n" "$string3" 
done < file
```

Or perhaps just

```
while read pos; do 
    string1=`printf "%s" $pos | cut -c 20-38`
    string2="=$pos" 
    printf "%s=%s\n" "$string1" "$string2"
done < file
```

Output

```
1234567890QWERTYUXY=abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz
```

That said, your original script works for me too. :-/

Output

```
1234567890QWERTYUXY abcdefghi1234567890QWERTYUXY.tar.gz
```